# ASP.NET MVC 3 Cascading combobox doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two comboboxes. First comobobox I populate in such way and it works fine:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Town, 
new SelectList(Model.Towns, "Value", "Text"),
"-- Select town --")

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Towns
    {
        get
        {
            List<DataRow> TownsListDB = OracleSelect("select * from Towns");
            List<SelectListItem> townsItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow rw in TownsListDB)
            {
                townsItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = rw[0].ToString(), 
                Text = rw[1].ToString() });
            }

            return townsItems;
        }
    }
```

And depends on the town, I want to show a list of hospitals:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Hospital, 
Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
"-- Select hospital --")
```

My jQuery code is:

```
 $('#Town').change(function() {
    var selectedTown = $(this).val();
    if (selectedTown != null && selectedTown != '') {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Hospitals")', { town: selectedTown },
         function           (hospitals) {
            var hospitalsSelect = $('#Hospital');
            hospitalsSelect.empty();
            $.each(hospitals, function(i, hospital) {
                hospitalsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: hospital.value,
                        text: hospital.text
                    }));
            });
            }); 
    }
 });
```

and C#:

```
        public ActionResult Hospitals(string town)
        {
            var modelHospital = new MedicalViewModel();
            List<DataRow> HospitalsListDB = modelHospital.OracleSelect
            ("select * from Hospitals hh where hh.TownID = " + town);
            List<SelectListItem> hospitalsItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow rw in HospitalsListDB)
            {
//example:
//rw[0]=101111
//rw[1]=Dublin
                hospitalsItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = rw[0].ToString(), 
                Text = rw[1].ToString() });
            }
            return Json(
                hospitalsItems,
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(hospitalsItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But it doesn't work. If I use this code as a Return result, then it's ok:

```
  return Json(Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                );
```

Why combobox doesn't work with my List result from DB?

Comment: It looks good. Does it brake somewhere, or does it simply return an empty list? If it breaks, what's the error message. If it returns an empty list, have you double-checked that the query returns anything?

Comment: Have you looked to see what is happening in Firebug/Developer tools when you shange the dropdown, you should be able to see what gets posted, and what is returned in the response.

Comment: I'm new in asp.net and jQuery, debugging jQuery helped me to found out the error, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
return Json(hospitalsItems.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Instead of this in last line

```
return Json(hospitalsItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Why should he have to make it ToList()? HospitalsItems is already a list of SelectListItems.

Comment: I found out what was the problem. It sounds funny I just needed capital letters in my jQuery code:  
`code
    select.append($('<option/>', {
    value:hospital.Value,
    text: hospital.Text
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. It sounds funny I just needed capital letters in my jQuery code: code select.append($('', { value:hospital.**Value**, text: hospital.**Text** }